# Regular expression which does not match at a certain capitalization

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression (in JS, but I don't think that it matters) which matches all upper case/lower case possibilities of a certain string but one.

Example: Let my string be "aBc". Then my regular expression should match like the following

```
var regex=/ABC|ABc|AbC|Abc|aBC|abC|abc/g;
```

In this case it is possible to spell it out but in general a string with n word characters allows 2^n-1 strings to match. For big n this is not well scaled anymore. Therefore I look for another way.

Edit: Since many of you don't seem to get my point: The regex must NOT match "aBc". So it's like /abc/i but not /aBc/.

For simplicity you can check if you expression does what it is supposed to do here: http://regex101.com/r/kP5aX2

Your regex should match exactly like mine.

Comment: try /[a-c]+/i   note the /i part

Comment: This would match "aBc" and many other string I don't want to be matched like "a", "cba" and so on.

Comment: So, just to check I understand you, in the example you want to match any capitalisation of the string `abc` _except_ `aBc`?

Comment: Yeah. The regex should match exactly like the given one but without numerating all possible matches.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
var regex = /(?!aBc)[a-cA-C]{3}/g;
```

`(?!aBc)` is a so called negative lookahead, which should do the trick you desire..

**UPDATE:**

to refer to the comments...

```
var regex = /((?![a-zA-Z]*aBc[a-zA-Z]*)[a-zA-Z]*[aA][bB][cC][a-zA-Z]*)/g;
```

**UPDATE 2**

if you dont want to match the whole words, but only the 3-character -trings, you should do it like that

```
var regex = /(?!aBc)[aA][bB][cC]/g;
```

see http://regex101.com/r/jQ3hS8

Comment: Furthermore it doesn't match "qabc" although that string contains "abc".

Comment: alrigth, in this case i didn't get the question rigth. see my update which also matches what you want.. but its messy, could be optimized maybe...

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made me find my submitted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is **just** 'abc' or 'AbC' etc, this will work:

```
/(?!aBc)[aA][bB][cC]/g
```

Comment: I guess /^(?!aBc)[aA][bB][cC]/g does the same but is shorter. The problem is that I want to look for such expressions in a long text. Therefore it is not enough if it only matches occurrences at the beginning.

Comment: I added a check to my question. I hope that helps you. Thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/\b(?!aBc)(?i)abc\b/
```

This will match all word like `abc`, `abC`, ... except `aBc`.

If you want to match `abc` even inside a word, remove the word boundary:

```
/(?!aBc)(?i)abc/
```

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain: Just remove the word boundary. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Due to nozzleman I found a very nice solution:

```
var regex=/(?!aBc)(?i)aBc/g;
```

I like the solution so much because instead of "aBc" you can plug in any other string (you only have to do it twice since the string occurs twice in the regex). That's the kind of solution I was looking for since I need the expression for many different strings of different length.

Answer (score 0):

to match `abc` not in the form of small-caps-small
use this pattern:
`(?![a-z][A-Z][a-z])(?i)abc`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yL4sX4)